# Product of sums.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

What is the simplest form of the following expression?

$\prod_{i=1}^n(a_i+b)^2=(a_1+b)^2\times(a_2+b)^2\times\cdots\times (a_n+b)^2$.

My observation:
In expansion, we will obtain $\prod_{i=1}^na_i+b^2\prod_{i=n}^n+...$ by direct multiplication but this is not all terms.
I will be grateful if someone help to complete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to simplify the expression is to notice that the product of the squares is simply the square of the products:

\begin{align} \prod_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i}+b)^{2} &= (a_{1}+b)^{2} (a_{2}+b)^{2} \cdots 
(a_{n-1}+b)^{2}(a_{n}+b)^{2} \\ &=\big[(a_{1}+b)(a_{2}+b)
\cdots (a_{n-1}+b)(a_{n}+b)\big]^{2} \\ &=\bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{n}
(a_{i}+b)\bigg)^{2} \end{align}

Trying something different will only lead to unnecessary messy algebra.

Comment: Good advice, but unfortunately sometimes you stat with the "ugly" and need to make it pretty. Then the uglier identities too are useful to know.

Comment: Thank you this will help. :-)